# Why does the military adviser stop giving me advice midway through a game?

Tags: civilization-5

Anytime I get about midway through a game of Civilization V, the military advisor stops giving me information about how strong most of my opponents are. That is, at the start of the game he will say something like:

> The Ottomans wield an empire that could wipe us off the face of the
>   planet

or

> The Chinese aren't quite as strong as us militarily

He will initially provide this information about each other player. This is useful information, but later in the game he only provides it for some other players, not all. Why is this? Also, what determines when he will stop providing this information?

Comment: I also noticed this and I also noticed he stopped informing me as the nations that are likely to start war against were planning on doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I loaded up a few old games, and in several of them my military adviser was informing me of the comparative military strength of other nations.  In one in particular, I was deep into the Modern Era, and late in the game, and he was still warning me about the might of the English army.

I don't know what the algorithm is specifically, but I believe advisers only provide information that is noteworthy.  In your case, it may be that as time passes, you and the other nations are reasonably matched by whatever criteria that is used to determine if the military adviser will take notice.

As time passes in the game, weaker civilizations are often wiped out in wars with their larger neighbors.  It's possible that surviving into the late game means that your military is comparable to others, so there's not much for the adviser to comment on.

Comment: I'm not sure it's as simple as not having much to say, as he always starts out including things like "We are about as strong as X", so it seems odd that he would say this initially but not later in the game.

Comment: @bgalin, primarily I'd challenge your assumption that this is something that goes away in the "late game" - in my case, I was near the End of Time and the adviser was still advising.  I don't know that we have more information about the algorithm than that, but I'll dig around and see.

Comment: I did indeed overlook that detail, and have thus updated the question. I'm interested in why the adviser would provide all information early, and only some later. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do you stop sending scouts out after you have explored the map?

I think the military adviser only knows about units you have seen in near past.  So if you don't have scouts, or cavalry, or ships roaming around, then you won't know how strong the enemy armies are.

It works the other way around too.  If you have a weak army and you give open boarders to a stronger force, then they will send units through your territory, see how weak you are, and then attack.

Comment: This is possible I suppose, but early in the game I would receive the information even on opponents I hadn't scouted.

Comment: -1 This is wrong. The military adviser will comment on the size of an opponents army regardless of how much you've seen of them, all that matters is that you've met the civilization.